# python combination of several lists items

Tags: python, list, algorithm, python-itertools

I have several lists like: `[1,2,3],[1,3],[1,2,3,4]`. I need combinations of these values (length equal to the number of lists). Problem is that itertools.product doing all combinations (I don't want for example `(1,1,1)` because all items are same or `[(1,3,2),(2,3,1)]` because items 1 and 3 only switch. I wrote a solution, where items in the tuple are unique and the result does not contain the same tuple after sort

```py
a = list(itertools.product(*[[1,2,3],[1,3],[1,2,3,4]]))
res = []
for item in a:
    if (len(item) == len(set(item))):
        is_unique = True
        for r in res:
            if sorted(item) == sorted(r):
                is_unique = False
        if is_unique:
            res.append(item)
```

with this result:

```sh
[(1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 4), (2, 1, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
```

The first problem is, that this code is really time-consuming if I have several arrays and every array contains many values (positions). The second problem is that IT DEPENDS on the order in a tuple (the second position can be only 1 and 3) so I cant use `itertools.combination()` on all unique value from input lists.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: Did you use `itertools.combinations()`?

Comment: `itertools.combinations()` have as input only one list and I have more than one

Comment: What actually are the rules that tell you what the valid results are? If there are separate candidates for each position *anyway*, then why should it matter if you get two outputs that are the same in a different order? What are you planning to *do with* the results?

Comment: Each list to combination contains admissible values of different objects. This is the reason why the order of result matter.

Comment: So you want all combinations that have: 1) One item from each list   2) There are no duplicates in the result   3) Every result will be unique when sorted (there will be no permutations of a specific combination of items)
 Are all these correct?

Comment: @IoaTzimas Yes, this is correct. And the number of lists are not always the same (this is the only example with 3)

Comment: And for each group of permutations you always want to keep the first occurence, or any of them? For example it must be (1,3,4) because this has priority when running the loops, or it can be any other (eg (3,1,4))?

Comment: It can be any other, just without duplicates (so only one of these options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is good, however the for loop is very time consuming. Try this instead:

```
a = list(itertools.product(*[[1,2,3],[1,3],[1,2,3,4]]))
s = set()
res = []
for item in a:
    if (len(item) == len(set(item))):
        k=tuple(sorted(item))
        if k not in s: 
            res.append(item)
            s.add(k)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> print(res)
[(1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 4), (2, 1, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
```

Comment: Thanks! It is more than twice as fast not only because of "for loop" but because the sorting of the tuple is done only once for every tuple before saving to set.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `set` and `len` to filter out duplicates:

```py
ll = [[1,2,3],[1,3],[1,2,3,4]]

c1 = itertools.product(*ll)
# [(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 4), (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 3), (1, 3, 4), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 1, 4), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3), (3, 1, 4), (3, 3, 1), (3, 3, 2), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 4)]
c2 = set(frozenset(c) for c in c1)
# {frozenset({3, 4}), frozenset({1, 4}), frozenset({2, 3, 4}), frozenset({2, 3}), frozenset({1, 2, 4}), frozenset({1, 2}), frozenset({3}), frozenset({1}), frozenset({1, 2, 3}), frozenset({1, 3}), frozenset({1, 3, 4})}
c3 = set(c for c in c2 if len(c) == len(ll))
# {frozenset({1, 2, 3}), frozenset({2, 3, 4}), frozenset({1, 3, 4}), frozenset({1, 2, 4})}
```